# Problem in many-to-many relationship in .net entity model framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, entity-relationship

here is my code :

```
var q = (from m in context.aspnet_Users
                     where m.UserName.Equals(username)
                     select new { m, m.aspnet_Roles.SourceRoleName }).FirstOrDefault();
```

but it gets me error :

> The specified type member
>   'SourceRoleName' is not supported in
>   LINQ to Entities. Only initializers,
>   entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported.

How I can solve this it many-to-many relationship using a interface table but .net framework remove the interface table and generate association with table mapping to it which is many-to-many.

I need role name how I can get it in this kind of model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `aspnet_Roles` is collection navigation property on your `aspnet_User` entity and `SourceRoleName` is mapped property of your `aspnet_Role` entity you must rewrite it like:

```
var q = (from m in context.aspnet_Users
         where m.UserName.Equals(username)
         select new 
             { 
                 m, 
                 m.aspnet_Roles.Select(r => r.SourceRoleName) 
             })
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

If your `SourceRoleName` is computed property in your `aspnet_Role` entity (custom property in .NET code) you can't use it in linq-to-entities query. You must select whole `aspnet_Role` entity and then access its computed property.